# API versioning in strapi

Tags: node.js, strapi

so by default strapi puts APIs into the api folder. But what if i want to version my APIs like v1/v2/v3 etc?

I didn't see any file that has the route to api folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no api versioning provided by `Strapi` right now, but the feature is to be added soon and is there in their roadmap. Refer to their productboard [here](https://feedback.strapi.io/feature-requests/p/api-versioning).

If you scroll down in the page mentioned above, you could see the idea request
[image]

Comment: Strapi works fine but I really need the versioning since my app will have new data and I'll have to keep both new and old api at the same time. And for the idea I've also posted my requirements and submitted my idea as critical. Hope they add it soon.

Comment: Hi @FahimHoque,

Is there any solution provided by them?

Comment: @sagusara, No not yet. it's in their product board but they haven't implemented it yet